# How to host WordPress website on NGINX container using AWS FARGATE

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I need two containers in one task defination. One for wordpress and another for nginx, however the traffic should route from nginx to wordpress. This should be done using aws fargate.

How to connect two containers ? so that nginx should send traffic to wordpress container !

Answer (score 0):

In AWS Fargate, all containers in the same task can access each other at `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` over their respective ports.

Let's say you have Nginx configured to listen on port `80` and WordPress configured to listen on port `9000`. To setup Nginx and Wordpress as you describe, you would have your Application Load Balancer forward traffic to the Nginx container on port `80`, and you would configure Nginx to forward traffic to WordPress at `127.0.0.1:9000`.

Comment: @PiyushJadhav it fails how? What is the error message? Please provide all details necessary in order for someone to help you. You can absolutely run Wordpress/Nginx as two containers in a single ECS task, but you have provided almost zero information about your current setup, and what issues you are encountering, so it isn't possible for anyone to point out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I have just read your answer carefully, it seems I have not configured the Nginx image to forward traffic to WordPress, I am not sure how to configure Nginx image. Thanks!!!!

Comment: You absolutely have to map some EFS volumes into your Nginx and WordPress containers in order to run them on ECS. You would add an Nginx configuration file in the EFS volume you mount into the Nginx container with the appropriate configuration to forward requests to WordPress.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/running-wordpress-amazon-ecs-fargate-ecs/